# use multiple regex on a single column of dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named ingredients and it has multiple items in it. How do I seperate each of them into a different column?

```
Eg:    Type      Ingredients
       Hybrid    18.7% THC
                 1.62% Total Terpenes
                 0.61% Myrcene
       Indica    0.61% Myrcene
                 0.35% Ocimene
                 0.18% Limonene
```

I want to split ingredients column into multiple column as THC, Mycrene, Ocimene, Limonene etc with each column describing it's percentage

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by percentage with `\s+` for one or more spaces, assign to new columns and then forward filling missing values for `type` column, last reshape by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df[['per','ingr']] = df['Ingredients'].str.split('%\s+', expand=True)
df['Type'] = df['Type'].replace('', np.nan).ffill()

df = df.pivot('Type','ingr','per').astype(float)
print (df)
ingr   Limonene Myrcene Ocimene   THC Total Terpenes
Type                                                
Hybrid      NaN    0.61     NaN  18.7           1.62
Indica     0.18    0.61    0.35   NaN            NaN
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. I think it's because it also has '\n'

Comment: @HellyBhalodia - Can you create sample data by `d = df.head().to_dict('list')` ?